# Find singular value decomposition from related form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have $A = D_1 Q D_2$, where $D_1, D_2$ are diagonal matrices and $Q$ is orthogonal.

Is there a way to find the singular value decomposition (SVD) of $A$ beyond just outright decomposing it?

Intuitively the two forms are really close to each other.

Comment: These forms may *seem* similar, but they're actually quite different. If $D_1 = I$ or $D_2 = I$, it is already an SVD. So, this may be observed as an SVD updating problem under diagonal pre- or post-multiplication, which - as far as I know - doesn't have a known solution. IMO, try at MathOverflow.